# filtering and though a sharepoint list items with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have tried below but not getting any result back
Not sure if i'm doing this well.
Can i filter in the foreach or in my if statement
Thanks in advance

```
[DateTime] $CreatedDate = $item["Created"] 
$convertedCreatedDate = $CreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$today = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

foreach ($item in $list.items | where {$convertedCreatedDate -eq $today}) {

    if ($list.items | where {$convertedCreatedDate -eq $today}) 
    {
        Write-Host $item["Created"] 
    }

    Write-Host $item["Created"] 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a complex expression in your `foreach` as you're doing above.  I would wrap it in a `@()` to make the code a bit more readable and to ensure the result is an array (either length 0, 1 or n) e.g.:

```
foreach ($item in @($list.items | where {$convertedCreatedDate -eq $today})) {
```

You can also simplify you're date testing by using the `Date` property on a DateTime e.g.:

```
$convertedCreatedDate = ([DateTime]$item["Created"]).Date
$today = (Get-Date).Date
```

You can also put a complex expression within an `if` statement condition but PowerShell will only evaluate whether the statement is `$true` or `$false`.  PowerShell does lots of coercion to try to take something like:

```
$list.items | where {$convertedCreatedDate -eq $today}
```

And convert that to a boolean. Essentially if the pipeline evaluates to a non-empty result, the result is `$true` otherwise it is `$false`.  This is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$today=(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

foreach ($item in $list.items) {
    [DateTime]$CreatedDate=$item["Created"]
    $convertedCreatedDate=$CreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    if ($convertedCreatedDate -eq $today) {
        Write-Host $item["Created"] 
    }
}
```